# the meaning of 'with a little flip' here

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Henrietta spent hours taking care of those nails, touching up chips
>   and brushing on new coats of polish. She’d sit on her bed, polish in
>   hand, hair high on her head in curlers, wearing the silky slip she
>   loved so much she hand-washed it each night. She never wore pants, and
>   rarely left the house without pulling on a carefully pressed skirt and
>   shirt, sliding her feet into her tiny, open-toed pumps, and pinning
>   her hair up **with a little flip** at the bottom, “just like it was dancin
>   toward her face,” Sadie always said.

*The Immortal Life of Henrietta Lacks by Rebecca Skloot*

Does this mean giving a little shake with her fingers? I can't visualize this.

Comment: In women's hairdos of my youth in the 50s and 60s a 'flip' was a fairly wide falling tress ending in a strong upward curl, like [this](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/d1/f6/23/d1f623f11f767e6f18648e4acb9ed695.jpg)

Comment: As @StoneyB has recalled +1 [here](http://www.hairfinder.com/hairstyles14/hairstyle-kl15g.jpg). It should not be confused with **hair flip** (the action) as [here](http://creditplushealth.org/health%20picture/Anna%20Kournikova%20Hair%20Flip.jpg)

Comment: Thank you. Do any one of you mind posting a short answer so I can wrap this question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your passage comes from the award winning book *The Immortal Life of Henrietta Lacks* which recounts the life and times of the donor of one of the oldest and most common human cell lines used in scientific research: [**HeLa**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HeLa).  Henrietta Lacks died in 1951 from cervical cancer.

In women's hairdos of the 50's and 60's a ***flip*** was a fairly wide falling tress ending in a strong upward curl. *(ref: @StoneyB)*
[image: here]

It should not be confused with ***hair flip*** which is an action used by persons with long hair to gain attention or when flirting
[here http://creditplushealth.org/health%20picture/Anna%20Kournikova%20Hair%20Flip.jpg](http://creditplushealth.org/health%20picture/Anna%20Kournikova%20Hair%20Flip.jpg)